# C# Write Code Method，Constructor parameter need inherit DbContext and Implementation customize Interface class

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I try to use two subprojects in one solution file:

- First project - let's call it `A` project - is a database project，It implements EF Core classes, lets other project call into the database
- Second project - let's call it `B` project - is some special function implementation, it needs to create some table to work, it also defines classes to all about table service

Here is my code - in `B` project - define an interface like this:

```
public interface IDefineContext 
{
    DbSet<TokenTable> TokenTables { get; set; }
}
```

In `A` project, I have a class implementing that interface:

```
public class APIDemoContext : DbContext, IDefineContext 
{
    public APIDemoContext(DbContextOptions<APIDemoContext> options): base(options)
    {
    }

    // some table
    public DbSet<Table1> Table1 { get; set; }

    // Interface table
    public DbSet<TokenTable> TokenTables { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my question:

In project `B`, I want to define `TokenTables` CRUD function service.

So I created this class:

```
public class TokenTableServices
{
    private IDefineContext  _context;

    public FreshTokenTableService(IDefineContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public void AddTokens(TokenTable data) 
    {
        _context.FreshTokenTables.Add(data);
        _context.SaveChange();    // Can't find this method
    }
}
```

How can I do that?

I want to let ASP.NET Core API project call like this

```
private TokenTableServices service;

public IActionResult SomeAction(string UserID)
{
    TokenTable  data = CreateToken(UserID);
    service.AddTokens(data);
}
```

Thanks~~

I'm trying to use generic type in constructor like this

```
public FreshTokenTableService<T>(T context) where T : DBContext,IDefineContext 
{
    _context = context;
}
```

But this look can't pass compiler

Comment: The EF Core method is **`SaveChanges()`** (plural as in **Changes** - not singular)

Answer (score 1):

The error is because your second project only knows of the capabilities of the DbContext through the interface you defined. If you want to expose the `DbContext.SaveChanges()` method you would need to add that signature to your interface.

```
public interface IDefineContext 
{
    DbSet<TokenTable> TokenTables { get; set; }

    int SaveChanges();
}
```

Since you are exposing a `DbSet` via this interface, which is a concrete type of EF, a better alternative you might have is to use a base class for DbContext(s) that expose the Token table:

```
public abstract class TokenDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<TokenTable> TokenTables { get; set; }

    protected TokenDbContext(DbContextOptions options) : base (options) { }
}
```

Then in your APIDemoContext:

```
public class APIDemoContext : TokenDbContext
{
    // Define DbSets, does not define TokenTables as that is available through base class.
}
```

And your service:

```
public FreshTokenTableService(TokenDbContext context)
{
    _context = context;
}
```

This automatically gives your service access to the functionality of the base DbContext class like `SaveChanges()` while exposing the desired `DbSet<TokenTable>` while hiding the other DbSets used by the supplying project.

Comment: Thank for U answer，looks good!!  i will try your code，and also need try ef core command(Migration、update-database...)，please wait some days

Answer (score 0):

In your TokenTableServices class you have:

`private IDefineContext _context;` and then you're using that again in your constructor (injection)... You're not trying to define context though, looks like you want to use the context you defined in APIDemoContext so inject that instead:

```
private readonly APIDemoContext _apiDemoContext;

public FreshTokenTableService(APIDemoContext context)
{
    _apiDemoContext = context;
}
```

Now you should be able to call `_apiDemoContext.SaveChangesAsync();`

I also don't recommend making a generic interface for your dbContext either.  It's fine that you want to have multiple dbContext in different project, but I think it's bad when you start passing them through generic interfaces.  Instead to make life and maintenance easier, I would create a common project and have your dbContext classes use or inherit from whatever you want in your new common project.

Comment: Thank for you answer，But ，in your code will lose project functional，I design project B is for lot of  mvc or api project ，each project have own database ，in my case，project A is depency an api project，project B is for any project need token service。

Thank for U again

Answer (score 0):

I Get some idea and it work!

all change is in project B FreshTokenTableService.cs

```
public class FreshTokenTableService <T> where T : DbContext,IDefineContext {
    private T _context;
    public FreshTokenTableService (T context){
        this._context = context;
    }
    
    public TokenTable GetData(int ID)
    {
        return _context.TokenTable.FirstOrDefault();  //I will work，Here is Example
    }

}
```

in API Porject，Controller can use DI get Project A `APIDemoContext` so Example API Controller Is

```
[ApiController]
public class AuthController : ControllerBase
{
    private FreshTokenTableService<APIDemoContext> _FreshTokenTableService;
    public AuthController(APIDemoContext context)
    {
        _FreshTokenTableService = new FreshTokenTableService<APIDemoContext>(context);
    }
}
```

Here Is My Code and it work
It also fits my development habits
but i'm sure `FreshTokenTableService` and use DI
I don’t know if writing like this is with the core idea of ​​.NET Core

Thank [@Eric Milliot-Martinez] [@Steve Py] answer my question